# mypy and basic inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, type-hinting, mypy

Got this pretty straight-forward inheritance case.

I read a bunch of `mypy` documentation but still can't figure out how to properly deal with those basic cases.

It's very standard OOP inheritance to me so I can't imagine `mypy` doesn't have a clean way to deal with those cases.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Parent:
    a: int = 0

    def __add__(self, other: Parent) -> Parent:
        a = self.a + other.a
        return self.__class__(a)


@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    b: int = 0

    def __add__(self, other: Child) -> Child:
        a = self.a + other.a
        b = self.b + other.b
        return self.__class__(a, b)


obj1 = Child(1)
obj2 = Child(1, 42)
print(obj1 + obj2)
```

`mypy` error message:

```
foo.py:18: error: Argument 1 of "__add__" is incompatible with supertype "Parent"; supertype defines the argument type as "Parent"
foo.py:18: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
foo.py:18: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides
```

Versions:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.10.4
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.971 (compiled: yes)
```

Comment: Follow-up question / comment: if I don't need to override the `__add__` function, mypy will fail to detect that a Parent method that returns `self.__class__(...)` actually returns a Child instance when called from a Child, therefore potentially raising not existing issues somewhere in the projet

Comment: "It's very standard OOP inheritance". No, it's wrong. No reasonable statically typed language will allow this. You cannot **restrict** the interface in a subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your follow-up comment, I assume you were actually interested in a way to have a generalized `__add__` method with proper type inference for `mypy` and other type checkers. Generics, as always, save the day.

Here is a working example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="Parent")

@dataclass
class Parent:
    a: int = 0

    def __add__(self: T, other: T) -> T:
        return self.__class__(**{
            field.name: getattr(self, field.name) + getattr(other, field.name)
            for field in fields(self.__class__)
        })

class Child(Parent):
    b: int = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = Child(a=1, b=2)
    c2 = Child(a=2, b=3)
    c3 = c1 + c2
    print(c3)
    reveal_type(c3)  # this line is for mypy
```

Output is of course `Child(a=3, b=5)` and `mypy` states:

```
note: Revealed type is "[...].Child"
```

Obviously, this will break once any subclass of `Parent` introduces a field with a non-addable type.

---

As for the subtyping issue, `mypy` actually tells you everything. You violated the LSP. This is not specific to `mypy` or even to Python. As @Wombatz said, this is just how types (and subtypes) have to work to be considered reasonable.

If you have a **subtype** of a type `T`, its interface must be a **superset** of `T`'s interface, never a strict subset.

### PS

Let me try and expand on the LSP issue a little bit with a slightly altered example.

Say I have the following parent and child classes:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Parent:
    n: float

    def __add__(self, other: Parent) -> Parent:
        return Parent(self.n + other.n)

class Child(Parent):
    def round_n(self) -> float:
        return round(self.n, 0)
```

Now I write a simple function that takes two instances of `Parent`, adds them and prints the result:

```py
def foo(obj1: Parent, obj2: Parent) -> None:
    print(obj1 + obj2)
```

So far so good. No problems here.

The signature of `foo` requires both arguments to be instances of `Parent`, which means they can also be instances **of any subclass** of `Parent`. That means they can also be instances of `Child`.

Assuming `foo` is internally type safe, each of the following calls is perfectly safe:

```py
parent = Parent(1.0)
child = Child(0.2)

foo(parent, parent)
foo(parent, child)
foo(child, parent)
foo(child, child)
```

The output obviously being `Parent(n=2.0)`, `Parent(n=1.2)`, `Parent(n=1.2)`, and `Parent(n=0.4)`.

But what happens, if I now decide to override the `__add__` method for the `Child` class restricting it to accept only other `Child` instances? Say I write it like this:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def __add__(self, other: Child) -> Child:
        return Child(self.round_n() + other.round_n())

    def round_n(self) -> float:
        return round(self.n, 0)
```

Ignoring the inheritance for a moment, this seems entirely reasonable and type safe. We annotated the `other` argument of `__add__` with `Child`, which tells the type checker that only instances of `Child` can be added to an instance of `Child`. That means we can safely call the `round_n` method on `other`, because all `Child` instances have that method.

Notably, `Parent` instances **do not** have the `round_n` method. But that is fine, since we annotated `other` in a way that *excludes* `Parent` instances.

But what about our `foo` function now?

Remember, it allows both arguments to be `Parent` instances, which implies `Child` instances as well. The whole idea behind the LSP comes into play here. We do not want to concern ourselves with specifics that *some* subclass of `Parent` may have. We assume that whatever a subclass does, will not break the `Parent` interface it inherits.

Specifically we assume that while a subclass may override the `__add__` method, nothing about those changes will **restrict** the way we can call it. Since `Parent.__add__` can be called with `other` being any instance of `Parent`, we assume that `Child.__add__` can also be called with **any** instance of `Parent`.

How could it be otherwise? There can be infinitely many subclasses of `Parent` and `foo` can not possibly be expected to verify that each of their interfaces is still compatible with that of `Parent`. That is what being a **subtype** should guarantee. **That** is the Liskov Substitution Principle:

If `foo` is correct and it accepts arguments of type `Parent`, then substituting an argument of subtype `Child` must not impact the correctness of `foo`.

We already established that `foo` is correct. However if try the same calls as before now (with the altered `Child` class), one of them will fail:

```py
foo(child, parent)
```

It fails (predictably to us) with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...].py", line x, in <module>
    foo(child, parent)
  File "[...].py", line y, in foo
    print(obj1 + obj2)
  File "[...].py", line z, in __add__
    return Child(self.round_n() + other.round_n())
AttributeError: 'Parent' object has no attribute 'round_n'
```

We are passing a `Parent` as `other` to `Child.__add__`, which does not work.

I hope this illustrates the issue a bit better.

---

What to do now?

Aside from the suggestions in the linked post, the dirtiest solution would be the following:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def __add__(self, other: Parent) -> Child:
        if not isinstance(other, Child):
            raise RuntimeError
        return Child(self.round_n() + other.round_n())

    def round_n(self) -> float:
        return round(self.n, 0)
```

This is technically correct, just not very nice to any user. A user would probably expect that he can *actually* use the `Child.__add__` method with `other` being a `Parent`, so in practice you would probably implement *some* logic to return something reasonable like so:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def __add__(self, other: Parent) -> Child:
        if not isinstance(other, Child):
            return Child(self.round_n() + other.n)
        return Child(self.round_n() + other.round_n())

    def round_n(self) -> float:
        return round(self.n, 0)
```

Notice by the way, that restricting the **return type** to a subtype is no problem. Since this post is way too lang as it is, I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to deduce why that is the case.

Comment: I have no doubt mypy doesn't complain but to me it looks like a very unnatural implementation which sole purpose is to trick mypy. And, as you said, the limitations are obvious. I don't quite understand your comment supporting @Wombatz's, which I'm sure are very well-founded. If I have a type Athlete that inherits from Person, it seems pretty natural to me that `Athlete::make_baby` returns an `Athlete` instance, while `Person::make_baby` returns a `Person` instance, right?

Comment: Maybe a simpler example would be the `copy` method, which quite obviously returns an instance of the class you call it from, not the parent class. `Person::copy()->Person` vs `Athlete::copy()->Athlete`. Right? Or am I insane?

Comment: @ben No, you are not insane. There just seems to be a misunderstanding regarding the root of the problem. Your expectation is reasonable and in fact covered by the LSP. **Return values** can be restricted to subtypes. It is just that **arguments** must not. An `Athlete` should still be able to make a baby with a `Person`. Even if he then forces his baby to also become an `Athlete`.  I expanded my answer in an attempt to explain the reasoning behind this with an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking so much time explaining it. I'll bury myself in LSP and hopefully become a better programmer, therefore a better person! :-)